# Homeomorphism confusion

Tags: general-topology

I stumbled upon this excerpt as I was reading [Graph Theory](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~hahn/MAT6490/GraphTheoryIII.pdf) by Reinhard Diestel:

> A *polygon* is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is the union of finitely many straight line segments and is homeomorphic to the unit circle $S^1$, the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ at distance 1 from the origin.

So based on this, how could *any* polygon be homeomorphic to $S^1$ even though both sets are of different cardinality?

Pardon me if the question is too basic; I'm totally new to topology and I probably am overlooking a detail.

Comment: Why do the two sets have different cardinality ?

Comment: Why do you think the sets have different cardinality? A polygon is the set of points defined by the union of the sets that are defined by line segments, not the set of line segments.

Comment: I'm _assuming_ so, I honestly don't know.

Comment: OK, why are you assuming it?

Comment: In that case, the first thing you should do is find a bijection between a line segment like $[0,1)$ and $S^1$.

Comment: I just realized what my mistake was.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a conceptual answer to your question.  Two curves are homeomorphic if the first can be continuously deformed into the second.  Intuitively, if you had a circular loop of wire, you could hammer and bend it into the shape of any polygon (without breaking the wire or adding any new connections).

The cardinality of $S^1$ is the same as the cardinality of any line segment, which in turn has the same cardinality as any finite union of line segments.  Cardinality of a set is different from "length" or "measure".  For example, though $[1,2]$ is a proper subset of $[0,3]$, the two sets have the same cardinality.